# Unable to associate existing virtual network moved from a resource group to another in which creating new virtual machine through azure portal

Tags: azure, networking, virtual-machine

I'm unable to associate the existing virtual network after moved from one resource group to the required resource group in which I am trying to create new virtual machine in the required resource group through ARM azure portal.

[image: Existing virtual network not showing]

Comment: Of-course VNet has been moved to the new resource group but the location is not changed to the location of new resource group. The Location of VNet was the same as before moving.

Comment: If possible, I want to check your VNet, in the same location and subscription. The Vnet is a arm mode Virtual Network? If possible, could you share it as a snapshot. Of course, remove sensitive information.

Comment: It is in the same subscription but not same as the location of resource group and arm mode only, not classic.

Comment: Yes, They are different.

Comment: Your resource group is not in `Southeast Asia` and  you create a VM select location in `Southeast Asia`? If this, I think you could select Southeast Asia VNet.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I understand that the VNet location will not be changed when it is moved with new one. It is better to recreate Vnet as similar with VM location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error log, please ensure your VNet is in the `Southeast Asia` and in the same subscription.

Note: When you move VNet from one resource group to another resource group with new different location, the location of VNet does not change.